How to overload a 2d vector operator[] to index it by passing a std::pair directly?
I am trying to add an overload to vector <vector  > to use a std::pair for indexing, basically:
vector<vector<int>> v(1, vector<int>(1, 7));
pair <int, int> p = {0, 0};
// v[p] should return v[p.first][p.second], which is 7.

So i tried this:
int& operator[](vector<vector<int>>& v, pair<int, int>& p) 
{
    return v[p.first][p.second];
}

And I get Overloaded 'operator[]' must be a non-static member function.
So is there any way to achieve this on std::vector itself, however messy?
P.S. I know this is bad practice, and I wouldn't use it in a real codebase, but I'm just wondering how such functionality could be implemented.
Edit: To clarify, I wanted to overload std::vector itself so that the overload would be compatible even if code wasn't written by me or generally if I wanted to plug-and-play in any code that uses std::vector directly without modifying existing code. (Especially in CP, so compactness would be nice)
However, it looks like I can only use my own class/wrapper. Oh well :(

Why not wrap your std::vector<std::vector<int>> in your own class, then you might have int& MyMatrix::operator[](std::pair<int, int>).

Look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Array_subscript_operator - the last part introduced in 2023 is nice for this. (You still need a wrapper for the vector case though.)

@Jarod42 Well, it seems overkill for just wanting to add an overload, but mainly, I just want to not have to restructure my code to use a different class whenever I want to use a simple shortcut, and maintain the readability of my code if I'm sharing a snippet using the overload.

If your goal is to not restructure your code in the future, then a wrapper, or some interface class is still a good idea. If instead of using operator[] you change your calls to sth.getAt(int x, int y); it will be easier to simply use your types that implement this interface, e.g. struct MyMatrix{ std::vector<std::vector<int>> dat; int& getAt(int x, int y){ return dat[x][y]; }};

Question : Why a std::pair and  not an explicit struct of your own making?  E.g. struct Index2D{ std::size_t row; std::size_t column; };  That gets rid of the meaningless first and second and some of the overhead of std::pair, And you will add some semantic meaning that avoid accidently use of other std::pair<int,int>.
